# python html mail failure

Tags: python, html, email

I'm struggling to figure out what went wrong with the below code. 
I'm trying to send html mail.

```
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()

 def sendEmail(msg):
    global NOW
    global SENDER
    global EMAILTARGET
    today = "%s/%s/%s" % (NOW.month,NOW.day,NOW.year)
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "SAR Data Report - %s" % today
    msg['From'] = SENDER
    msg['To'] = EMAILTARGET
    chunk = MIMEText(msg, 'html')
    msg.attach(chunk)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(SENDER, EMAILTARGET, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

the above code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./html_mail.py", line 295, in <module>
 sendEmail(html)
 File "./html_mail.py", line 245, in sendEmail
 chunk = MIMEText(msg, 'html')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
  self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 226, in set_payload
  self.set_charset(charset)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 268, in set_charset
  cte(self)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 73, in encode_7or8bit
  orig.encode('ascii')
  AttributeError: MIMEMultipart instance has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your code is that you've used *msg* as an in-parameter to your function and it collides with your MIME message container (both named *msg*).

What you need to do is to change the name of the in-parameter to something else, like *html*:

```
def sendEmail(html):
...
chunk = MIMEText(html, 'html')
...
```

Comment: If you want to avoid all the hassles with SMTP I would recommend an email delivery service like [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se) or [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `msg`, which is a `MIMEMultipart` object, to the `MIMEText` initializer, which expects a string. You should be passing a string containing the HTML you want to attach, not the message you're trying to attach it to.